# Azure Service Bus returning just one message

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I Have 9 messages in my currente Queue, I wish to get all messages and return in a List, I also tried the code below:

```
List<MessageHandler> messages = new List<MessageHandler>();
         MessageHandler _message = new MessageHandler();
         string body = string.Empty;
         if (deleteMessagesOnReceive)
            client = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
         else
            client = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);


         client.RegisterMessageHandler
         (
             async (message, token) =>
             {
                _message.MessageSequenceNumber = message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber;
                _message.MessageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
                _message.DateExpire = message.ExpiresAtUtc;
                messages.Add(_message);
                await client.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
             }
         );

         return messages;

but always return 1 message in random order.

There's some way to pick all messages?
```

I am using .net core!!

Answer (score 1):

You're using OnMessage API, where register a callback with message handler provided by the SDK. You will be always given one message per callback invocation and this is supposed to be your message pump.

If you need to fetch several messages in a single operation (a batch), you should use [`ReceiveAsync()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/f68c68cddb7aaa19daadf46623b7cc564a859e9f/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Core/MessageReceiver.cs#L283) overload that accepts number of requested messages, using either a specific client or the general `MessageReceiver` class.

Comment: I understand ,but we don't have the ReceveAsync() method availabe on driver Service Bus on .net core

Comment: Not sure I understand... Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package, which targets .NET standard, has a class `MessageReceiver` with `Task<IList<Message>> ReceiveAsync(int maxMessageCount, TimeSpan serverWaitTime)` method.

Comment: Yes in .NET standard we can implement this method, but also at .NET Core 1.01 de Azure Service bus driver version 2.0.0 preview we can't implement. I think I will move to .NET standard :|

Comment: They joy of the .net chaos ATM 